# Store API outcomes into a new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, api, store

I have a data frame on name (df) as follows.

```
ID name
1 Xiaoao
2 Yukata
3 Kim
4 ...
```

Examples of API are like this.

```
European-SouthSlavs,0.2244 Muslim-Pakistanis-Bangladesh,0.0000 European-Italian-Italy,0.0061 ...
```

And I would like to add a new column using API that returns nationality scores up to 39 nationalities and I would like to list up to top 3 scores per name. My desired outcomes as follows.

```
ID name score nat
1 Xiaoao 0.7361 Chinese
1 Xiaoao 0.1721 Korean
1 Xiaoao 0.0721 Japanese
2 Yukata 0.8121 Japanese
2 Yukata 0.0811 Chinese
2 Yukata 0.0122 Korean
3 Kim 0.6532 Korean
3 Kim 0.2182 Chinese
3 Kim 0.0981 Japanese
4 ... ... ...
```

Below is my some of scratch to get it done. But I failed to get the desired outcomes for a number errors.

```
df_result <- purrr::map_dfr(df$name, function(name) {
  result <- GET(paste0("http://www.name-prism.com/api_token/nat/csv/",
                       "API TOKEN","/", URLencode(df$name)))
  if(http_error(result)){
    NULL
  }else{
    nat<- content(result, "text")
    nat<- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(nat, split = "(?<=\\d)\n", perl=T)[[1]],","))
    #first three nationalities
    top_nat <- nat[order(as.numeric(nat[,2]), decreasing = T)[1:3],]
    c(df$name,as.vector(t(top_nat)))
  }
})
```

First, the results of top scores were based on the entire data rather than per name.
Second, I faced an error saying "Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:! Argument 1 must have names."

If you can add any comments on my codings, I will appreciate it!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The output of each iteration of the map_dfr should be a dataframe for which to bind rows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

df <- data.frame(name = c("Xiaoao", "Yukata", "Kim"))

map_dfr(df$name, function(name) {
  data.frame(name = df$name, score = sample(1:10, 1))
})
```

Instead of concatenating name with top_nat at the end of your function, you should be making it a data.frame!